# Run Jenkins pipeline on local information if SCM is not accessible

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline

I have developed a pipeline job defined by a Pipeline script from SCM. I use Git as SCM. Most of the time, the Git server is accessible and there is no problem but some time the git server is unavailable due to network issue for example.

In this case, the job is in failure. Jenkins raises the following exception :
'''hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress --prune -- origin +refs/tags/...:refs/remotes/origin/..." returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to access '...': Failed to connect to Proxy port 8080: Connection timed out'''

In this context, I would like to manage this exception because during a preceding job execution, I have already get the pipeline script from SCM. To my mind we could use the preceding code already downloaded from the git server.

Is it a way to manage this kind of exception to exploit local information?

Below is my pipeline script

```
pipeline { 
  agent { node 'master' } 

  options { 
    disableConcurrentBuilds() 
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '60')) 
    skipDefaultCheckout() 
  } 
  
  stages { 
    stage("Checkout ft4cs-engine for subsystem report generation") { 
      steps { 
        timestamps { 
          script { 
            echo "Checkout repository" 
            dir('repository') { 
              try { 
                checkout([
                  $class: 'GitSCM', 
                  branches: [[name: "${REPO_BRANCH}"]], 
                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                  extensions: [
                    [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**'], 
                    [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']
                  ], 
                  submoduleCfg: [], 
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitrepo', url: '<url gitlab>']]
                ]) 
              } 
              catch (Exception e) { 
                echo "Catching exception during the checkout step : $e"; 
              } 
            } // end of dir
          }   // end of script
        } // end of timestamps
      } // end of steps 
    } // end of stage
  ... 
  } // end of stages
} // end of pipeline
```

Best regards

Comment: Please show your Pipeline script

Comment: My pipeline script is quite long and I can't share it totaly. But I will try to give you main information just below. First of all I have activated the option "Force polling before using workspace" and add exception management on git checkout

Comment: pipeline {
  agent { node 'master' }
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '60'))
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  stages {
    stage("Checkout ft4cs-engine for subsystem report generation") {
      steps {
        timestamps {
          script {
            echo "Checkout repository"
            dir('repository') {
              try {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',

Comment: branches: [[name: "${REPO_BRANCH}"]],
                  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                  extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**'],
                  [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']],
                  submoduleCfg: [],
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitrepo', url: '<url gitlab>']]])
              } catch (Exception e) {
                echo "Catching exception during the checkout step : $e";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you try as following:

1. Define a Groovy varible `runCheckOut=true` at begging of pipeline
2. Add condition for checkout stage
3. In the `catch` change `runCheckOut=false`
4. In the `catch` load the Jenkinsfile

```
def runCheckout=true

pipeline { 
  agent { node 'master' } 

  options { 
    timestamps()
    disableConcurrentBuilds() 
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(daysToKeepStr: '60')) 
    skipDefaultCheckout() 
  } 
  
  stages { 
    stage("Checkout") { 
      when {
        expression {runCheckout}
      }
      steps { 
        script { 
          echo "Checkout repository" 
          dir('repository') { 
            try { 
              checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM', 
                branches: [[name: "${REPO_BRANCH}"]], 
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                extensions: [
                  [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**'], 
                  [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']
                ], 
                submoduleCfg: [], 
                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'gitrepo', url: '<url gitlab>']]
              ]) 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { 
              echo "Catching exception during the checkout step : $e"; 
              sh 'cp <path to your Jenkinsfile>  <path to your Jenkinsfile>.groovy'
              sh 'sed ...' // change runCheckout=true  to runCheckout=false
              load '<path to your Jenkinsfile>.groovy' // load new Jenkinsfile which will run all stages
            } 
          } // end of dir
        }   // end of script
      } // end of steps 
    } // end of stage
  ... 
  } // end of stages
} // end of pipeline
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition but it seems in my case that Jenkins cannot load the Jenkinsfile shared below because it cannot access to gitlab jennkins jobs repository. So I think that Jenkins has thrown the error before the execution of the content of Jenkinsfile, I remind you that I use the option "pipeline script from SCM".